# CosmosDB over MongoDB API does not return collection size

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to get collection size using db.command.stats() command. The response contains only document count. Such fields as size, avgObjSize and so one is 0. Official documentation says that CosmosDb supports collStats command. I also tried this command but response is the same. It returns only document count.

Comment: can you post the code ?

Comment: Sajeetharan, it is just a mongodb shell command.

Comment: @VadimMarchenko - this is the behavior I see as well, with and without preview features enabled. I'll pass this along to the team (really nothing that can be done here). FYI as Sajeetharan alluded to, it would have been much more helpful to include the actual, exact command you ran, even if it seems obvious to you (or that you assume it will be obvious to others). There are dozens of mongodb shell commands. And many parameters as well.

Comment: @VadimMarchenko - also, along with the exact command you ran, you could also add the output emitted from running the command (both for a native mongodb collection and a Cosmos DB (mongodb api) collection, to illustrate the difference, vs just a generic description. This is the type of detail that really helps.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thank you for the answer and very detailed explanation how to improve the question. I will update the question like you advised. .